# Pre-trained CNN for multi-output models

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, image-classification

How to use `Keras Applications` for a multi-output model?

I am trying to use VGG16 for a multi-output model but get an value error `ValueError: Input 0 of layer block1_conv1 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3 but received input with shape (None, 64, 64, 1)`. I am a bit lost and can't seem to find anything on multioutputs for VGG16 or any other Keras pre-trained application.

I am using this as a guide: [Transfer Learning in Keras with Computer Vision](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-use-transfer-learning-when-developing-convolutional-neural-network-models/)

```
# load model without classifier layers
base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH,3))
# add new classifier layers
sex_x = base_model.output
sex_x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(sex_x)
sex_x = Dropout(0.5)(gender_x)
output_sex = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(sex_x)

weight_x = base_model.output
weight_x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(weight_x)
weight_x = Dropout(0.5)(weight_x)
output_weight = Dense(1, activation='linear')(weight_x)
# define new model
model = Model(inputs=base_model.inputs, outputs=[output_sex, output_weight])

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss =['binary_crossentropy','mae',],metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(x_train,[y_train[:,0],y_train[:,1]],validation_data=(x_test,[y_test[:,0],y_test[:,1]]),epochs = 10, batch_size=128,shuffle = True)
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this error, your model input asks `3 channel` RGB but your data seems to be in `1 channel` (grayscale). Make sure you data has RGB images.

Comment: You could add to the answer that `tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb` can be used to convert 1 chanel grayscale to 3 chanel RGB

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it.